# error occur- Login failed for user ABLF\Guest in c#.net

Tags: c#

I have created an application using c# on visual studio 2005 and sqlserver 2005 in backend. 
My application is running perfectly on server machine but on client machine it is giving following error-

Login failed for user ABLF\Guest

I have installed it by going into my network places and then execute the setup(which i have created) from shared folder document and setting..

Comment: That's an SQL Server authentication error - does your site use windows authentication? If so, you probably want to setup SQL Server to do the same or use impersonation.

Comment: i want to know how you accessing the application. Are you using application from server or from client side ?

Comment: i have executed the application setup in client machine by accessing it through server machine

Comment: what is impersonation or how to setup SQL Server to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guest account is disabled on host machine. Guest account also does not have remote logon enabled by default.

To be safe you need to setup a remote user account that only has access to website on host. Do not enable Guest account! Too many hacks can use Guest account to enable privileges upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks..finally i got the solution actually from server's database i have to allow client machine to access database by setting security property then setting new userlogin to ablf\guest..